# Stop execution in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I´d like to know how can I stop execution in smalltalk. I entered an infinite loop and don´t want to loose the code that´s written. I tried using pause button but doesn´t seem to be right.

Comment: which dialect are you using? In Pharo you can use `cmd + .`

Comment: What Smalltalk implementation are you using? Gnu? Pharo? ...

Answer (score 2):

Normally, even if you are unable to stop execution, you should be able to get the code changes you made back from the .changes file. If you can restart the image, there is a 'recover lost changes' menu entry. Always first make a backup copy of the changes and image files before trying this. (In Pharo/Squeak. Other smalltalk have similar possibilities)

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the dialect and possibly keyboard settings.
try CMD-. or CTRL-., which works in most dialects.